# Creating Gradle file for REST-Web Service

Tags: java, rest, gradle, build.gradle

I am pretty new to gradle and want to create a buildfile for a REST-Service. After I read some introduction on the gradle homepage and some other pages I started a new project using the command `gradle init --type=java-project` because my service is Java based. The structure of the project was created and I wanted to insert my `.class` files into the directories. This is my first problem: I don´t know the proper structure for this kind of project. After this I focused on my dependencies, which I added. As soon as I want to build my project, an error occurs which has to do with the usage of jersey as technology. If I compile my service with eclipse, it works perfectly fine, so my code works.

So my 2 questions are:

**How to create an proper file structure ?**

**How to fix the issue with the Servlet/WAR-compilation**

---

Here is the structure of my project in eclipse:

```
RestWebService
|--Java Resources
|  |--src
|     |--com.name.restproject.rest
|     |  |--WebController.java         //contains the jersey REST service
|     |--com.name.restproject.service
|        |--ServiceUtil.java           //contains some util methods
|--Libraries
|  |--Apache Tomcat v7
|  |--asm-3.3.1.jar
|  |--EAR Libraries
|  |--gson-2.5.jar
|  |--jersey-bundle-1.14.jar
|  |--JRE SYSTEM Library
|  |--json-20151123.jar
|  |--Web App Libraries
|--JavaScript Resources
|--build
|--WebContent
   |--META-INF
   |  |--MANIFEST.MF
   |--WEB-INF
      |--lib
      |--fileName.properties           //File with Data for ServiceUtil.java
      |--configFile.xml                //File with Confc for ServiceUtil.java
      |--web.xml                       //Config for the REST paths
```

I have no plan where to place the two files from the WEB-INF directory. I have placed the structure under the projectfolder `/src/main/java/com/name/restproject`

Here is the gradle file of the project

**build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'

// In this section you declare where to find the dependencies of your project
repositories {
    // Use 'jcenter' for resolving your dependencies.
    // You can declare any Maven/Ivy/file repository here.
    mavenCentral()
}

// In this section you declare the dependencies for your production and test code
dependencies {
    // The production code uses the SLF4J logging API at compile time
    compile group: 'com.google.code.gson', name: 'gson-parent', version: '2.6'
    compile group: 'asm', name: 'asm-parent', version: '3.3.1'
    compile group: 'com.sun.jersey.glassfish.v3.osgi', name: 'jersey-gf-bundle', version: '1.1.4'
    compile group: 'org.json', name: 'json', version: '20151123'


    // Declare the dependency for your favourite test framework you want to use in your tests.
    // TestNG is also supported by the Gradle Test task. Just change the
    // testCompile dependency to testCompile 'org.testng:testng:6.8.1' and add
    // 'test.useTestNG()' to your build script.
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to create a REST web service with a Gradle build, I suggest you to use Spring Boot REST

**Spring Boot - Building a RESTful Web Service :** http://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/

It already contains a Gradle build : https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-rest-service/blob/master/initial/build.gradle

Also if you want to build a WAR instead of a JAR (which is default build configuration), you can follow this documentation : http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#build-tool-plugins-gradle-packaging